# Empty lldb.frame variables in Xcode lldb debugger when using Python scripts

Tags: python, c++, xcode, lldb

I am currently working on a plotting command for custom objects in C++. I am using Xcode v10.1.

I import my own commands with *command script import test.py* where there is a function as following:

```
import lldb

def test_function(debugger, command, result, dict):
        obj = lldb.frame.FindVariable("custom_object")
        print(obj)

def __lldb_init_module (debugger, dict):
  debugger.HandleCommand('command script add -f test.test_function test')
```

Where *custom object* is an object I want to use in the Python script.

If I have just opened the debugger I get the error:

```
obj = lldb.frame.FindVariable("custom_object")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'FindVariable'
```

However when I open the embedded Python interpreter in Xcode directly and execute the same line of code as above I get no error.

If I now execute my custom command again it executes successfully for all objects in the same scope of the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lldb.frame` is not defined in lldb python based commands - that's why it is `NoneType`.  `lldb.{process, thread,frame}` are just for convenience in the interactive script interpreter.  But it wouldn't make sense for a command - which might get run in a stop hook, a breakpoint command, etc. to rely on some global state for its process & thread.  After all, you could have two threads hitting the same breakpoint at the same time.  So there isn't a unique "lldb.thread".

It's better to use the version of the command function which takes a SBExecutionContext as the third argument (see: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html) and get the thread and frame from that argument.